# Calling dynamically-named counters

Tags: counters, csname

I have several pairs of counters, `Question` and `Subquestion`, `Example` and `Subexample`, etc. I'd like to set the child series to 1 whenever the parent series advances, and I'd like to arrange this for all of them in one command.

Is is possible to do something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Question}
\newcounter{Subquestion}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \stepcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{
         % Sub\MakeLowercase{#1}} % attempt 1
         % \csname Sub\MakeLowercase{#1}endcsname} % attempt 2
    }{1}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{Subquestion}{5}
\mycommand{Question}
\theSubquestion % should output 1

\end{document}
```

Comment: See \newcounter{name}[parent] or \counterwithin{name}{parent}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, that's nearly it, but it seems to set the child counter to 0 rather than 1.

Comment: One typically increments the counter before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest strategy would be to name the counters as `SubQuestion` and `SubExample`.

You should never need to call `\the<counter>` directly in a document, so what the macros internally do is unimportant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Question}
\newcounter{SubQuestion}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% <--- don't forget
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{Sub#1}{1}%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{Subquestion}{5}
\mycommand{Question}
\theSubQuestion % should output 1

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I can't see reasons for requiring the counter to be set at 1 instead of 0 (and incremented at the start of the subquestion, subexample or whatever).

If you want that choice of names, you need to do the lowercasing before feeding the name to `\setcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Question}
\newcounter{Subquestion}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% <--- don't forget
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    \setsubcounter{#1}{1}%
}
\newcommand{\setsubcounter}[1]{%
  \lowercase{\setsubcounteraux{#1}}% Apply \lowercase to #1
}
\newcommand\setsubcounteraux[1]{\setcounter{Sub#1}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{Subquestion}{5}
\mycommand{Question}
\theSubquestion % should output 1

\end{document}
```